# SynPS/2 Lifebook S935 not working at all How to fix?

Tags: touchpad

the SynPS/2 touchpad on my Lifebook S935 does not work at all.
xinput list it
xinput /proc/bus/input/devices lists it
an external mouse works correctly
Thouch pad does not respond at all

It works correctly under the native Windows 7 installation
thanks in advance, maurizio

Answer (score 1):

Just edit the file /etc/default/grub

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

change the line "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomux quiet splash" to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.notimeout i8042.nomux quiet splash"
```

save the file and then

```
sudo update-grub
```

reboot and have fun with the well working touchpad :-)